# How to get element properties from Metro W8?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm automation test engineer and performing automation using SilkTest

Is there any way to get active Metro window elements (e.g name, style, coordinates, sub-elements)?

Latest SilkTest 13.5 version do not see Metro objects at all :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could not figure out from the comments whether you are looking at options other than SilkTest. If you do then have a look at [RIATest](http://www.cogitek.com/riatest/features/technologies/windows.html) which **does** support Metro applications.

Stating from version 6.0 a number of features in RIATest are specifically targeted at Metro style application automation, particularly:

- Ability to stay on top of Metro UI to allow you to simultaneously see your Metro application and RIATest IDE and minimize switching from Desktop to Metro screens when automating a Metro application.
- Recording of actions performed on native Windows GUI elements (including Metro GUI). The recorder analyses your script code and reuses your variable names to generate cleaner recorded scripts similar to how you would hand-code an automation script.
- Seamless workaround for [bugs like this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779279/ui-automation-tree-is-broken-for-windows-8-store-application) in Windows UI Automation implementation in Metro UI.

*Disclaimer: I work for Cogitek, the RIATest company.*

Answer (score 0):

From the [SilkTest 13.5](http://supportline.microfocus.com/Documentation/books/ASQ/SilkTest/135/en/SilkTest_ReleaseNotes.pdf) release notes

[image]

Comment: Why you not just look at my comments? I already wrote it. I'm interesting to click by coordinates to element in Metro...

Comment: It wasn't clear from your comment that you realized SilkTest 13.5 explicitly does NOT support "Metro" applications.  So if you realize that, then should we interpret your question to NOT be about SilkTest at all?  If so that's fine, but I would rephrase the question so we realize you're looking for another option. IOW, don't include SilkTest in the question :)

Comment: Well, I will use Silk like clicker, but again, I need some application that will able to give me the list of applications on metro screen.

Comment: It could be exe application that will collect all required information.